# Buscar e mostrar informações de um único usuário pelo banco de dados

Tags: php

Queria saber se alguém pode me auxiliar neste código.

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Seja bem vindo

```
       $usuarioPF = $_SESSION['usuario_pf'];
       $senhaPF = $_SESSION['senha_pf'];
       $id = $_SESSION['idcpf'];
       $cpf = $_SESSION['cpf'];

       $sql = "SELECT nome,sobrenome FROM pessoa_fisica" or die('Nenhum resultado');;

       $result = $conecta->query($sql);

       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo $row["nome"]."  ". $row["sobrenome"];

       }}
```

**Pagina de cadastro**

```
<?php
session_start();

    include 'banco_dados/conexao_banco.php';

    mysqli_set_charset($conecta, 'utf8');

     if(isset($_GET['id_cpf'])){
        $id_cpf = $_GET['id_cpf'];}
     if(isset($_GET['nome'])){
        $nome = $_GET['nome'];}
     if(isset($_GET['sobrenome'])){
        $sobrenome = $_GET['sobrenome'];}
     if(isset($_GET['cpf'])){
        $cpf = $_GET['cpf'];
     if(isset($_GET['email'])){
        $email = $_GET['email'];}
     if(isset($_GET['dt_nasc'])){
        $dt_nasc = $_GET['dt_nasc'];}
     if(isset($_GET['endereco'])){
        $endereco = $_GET['endereco'];}
     if(isset($_GET['usuarioPF'])){
        $usuarioPF = $_GET['usuarioPF'];}
     if(isset($_GET['senhaPF'])){
        $senhaPF = $_GET['senhaPF'];}
        //fim do filtro

      //inserir dados na tabela pessoa_fisica  
    $stmt = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO `pessoa_fisica` (id_cpf,nome,sobrenome,cpf,email,dt_nasc,endereco,usuarioPF,senhaPF) "
            . "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('ississsss', $id_cpf, $nome, $sobrenome, $cpf, $email, $dt_nasc, $endereco, $usuarioPF,$senhaPF); 
    if(!$stmt->execute()) { 
        $erro = $stmt->error;  
    } else { 
        echo "<script>alert(' Cadastro realizado com sucesso! ')</script>";
         $_SESSION['idcpf'] = "$id_cpf";
         $_SESSION['cpf'] = "$cpf";
         $_SESSION['nome_pf'] = "$nome";
         $_SESSION['sobrenome_pf'] = "$sobrenome";
         $_SESSION['email_pf'] = "$email";
         $_SESSION['usuario_pf'] = "$usuarioPF";
         $_SESSION['senha_pf'] = "$senhaPF";
    } 
       }

?>
```

Eu queria que aparecesse somente o nome de um usuário específico do meu banco de dados de  dados, mas aparece todos os nomes , já tentei variareis de sessão mas não deu certo

Comment: Lembrando que já tentei utilizar a clausura  where com as variáveis de sessão e não deu certo.

Comment: Mas é a cláusura where que você vai definir quem quer que venha

Comment: Já experimentou tirar as aspas quando for setar a sessão? `$_SESSION['idcpf'] = $id_cpf;` e assim por diante?